# How to control the axes of individual subplots in catplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot, catplot

Consider the following data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['green','tree',2],
                   ['green','leaf',3],
                   ['red','tomato',1],
                   ['red','pepper',5],
                   ['red','apple', 1]], columns=['color', 'object', 'value'])
```

The dataframe looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

I'd like to use `seaborn.catplot` to produce a barplot of the various categories:

```py
sns.catplot(data=df, kind='bar', x='object', y='value', col='color');
```

[image]

However, I'd like to exclude the objects that don't belong to a given category (i.e. in the first graph I want to exclude `'tomato'`, `'pepper'` and `'apple'`, while in the second plot I want to exclude `'tree'` and `'leaf'`). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use seaborn's bar plot. I am creating two new columns based on your condition. You can then set the titles using for e.g. `ax1.set_title`

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 3))

mask = (df.color == 'green')

sns.barplot(x='object', y='value', data=df[mask], ax=ax1)
sns.barplot(x='object', y='value', data=df[~mask], ax=ax2)

ax1.set_title("color=green")
ax2.set_title("color=red")
```

You can also use `catplot` but that generates additional figures which you need to then close.

```
sns.catplot(data=df[mask], kind='bar', x='object', y='value', col='color', ax=ax1);
sns.catplot(data=df[~mask], kind='bar', x='object', y='value', col='color', ax=ax2);
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear: I don't want the columns that don't belong to a given category to show up. So in the plot on the left I don't want tomato, pepper and apple. In the plot on the right I don't want tree and leaf.